# How Does A Domain User Schedule A Task On Windows Workstation?

Tags: administrator, domain, windows-task-scheduler

My workstation is running Windows 10. The task schedule is running. 
[image]

I log into my workstation using a Domain user account, which also is in the Domain Administrators group.

For testing, I need to schedule a task on my workstation to see how it will perform, before setting the same task up on one of our Windows servers.

Before writing this post I checked to make sure that my task scheduler service is set up to run automatically and is currently running.

When I try to run the task. I get that familiar message I have seen in a lot of posts, but most of those posts I read have to do with making sure the Task Scheduler service is running. I believe my problem is different.

*Task Scheduler service is not available. Task Scheduler will attempt to reconnect to it.*

How should I be scheduling this task? Which account should be running it?

Comment: The service in question should be available and running, the fact it is not running, is an indication the installation is corrupt (or the image has been configured so the service is not running).  As the Administrator you will have to rule out the simple solution of simply starting the service. If that does not work then the installation is corrupt and you should do an in-place repair to resolve this problem.  My research into the error, indicates, this is only caused by system corruption (due to the service not running). *An answer to indicate to reinstall Windows isn't helpful IMO* Good Luck

Comment: The service is up and running, and I am getting that message. Is there another service that is stopped causing this? If so, what is the name of that service, and I'll make sure it is set to run. The name of the service is TaskScheduler, right? I've just added  a picture to the OP that was snapped from services right around the time I am posting this note.

Comment: Is anyone else on the domain having this problem on their workstation?